# Replacing diode in circuit analysis?

Tags: electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics

While analyzing circuits containing diodes in reverse bias I replace it with a pure insulator for simplifying things. Similarly can I replace a forward biased diode with a conductor and a varying resistance in series?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Electricity is also physics.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of the diode can be modelled by an exponential. Since the exponential function is not a linear one, it is not very useful for analisys. But, you can replace it by linear elements.

The most accurate way to do this is a voltage source in series with a resistor. See model 3 in teh picture.

[image: Different diode models]

You must know what values of voltage you're going to work with. For those voltages, draw the tangent line of the exponential.

The slope of that tangent line is the conductance $1/R$. The cut with the horizontal axis is the voltage of the source. Like this you get an accurate method. It's all in the picture, part 3.

However, this model is only valid locally. IF you vary voltages much, you should ocnsider drawing another line, closer to your work zone.

---

Since the resistance is always tiny, it is usually neglected. A small resistance means a big slope. So the diode is sometimes modelled as a vertical linea. That is a voltage source with no resistance in series. It's a coarser approximation. That's picture #2.

Finally, if the voltage is small compared to others, you can also neglect that voltage of the voltage source, so the diode is sometimes regarded as an open circuit, picture #1.

Answer (score 0):

An answer promoted from a comment:  yes, you can, but you should also add a constant voltage source to account for the bias voltage.